# (django) Why do I get an error when adding app to INSTALLED_APPS but not when just importing?

Tags: django, python-import

I wrote an app with abstract classes, some utils functions, my common template tags and so on.

Somewere I saw it's recommended way to do this stuff to a reusable app. (It's all related to each other.) Why not? It seems to be a good idea. So I made the stuff being part of an app. Since that app has no urls, views and not the normal structur, it's more like a python module. (But it needs django.)

---

When I import this app the normal way (with `import myapp` on top of the files) it works fine.

Looking for bestpractice I saw in the official django tutorial part 8 that's recommended to import apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. Since I made my utils module being an app I thought I could just add a line to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Just like this: `myapp.apps.MyappConfig`.

My project structure:

```
project
|-... [multiple normal apps]
|-myapp [which is my utils app]
|-project [the inner folder]
|-... [some other stuff]
```

As you can see, `myapp`, the utils app, is still part of the project (and hasn't been made a reusable app yet.)

---

But when I add that line to `INSTALLED_APPS` I get the following traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0xb6356adc>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/my_cool_directory/project/myapp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .models import *
  File "/my_cool_directory/project/myapp/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Publishable(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
```

---

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

---

It's not like I have I serious problem because I can import the app the normal way. I'm just curious: Why isn't it working the recommended way?

---

- And: how to make things in submodules to be importable from topmodule? In apps.py? Or in `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import your models into the root module of your app. That's one of the limitations of Django's application framework. You need to remove the `from .models import *` line from `myapp/__init__.py`.

Django first imports the root module of every installed application. This is used to set up the application configs, which are needed to set up relational fields between models in different apps. To set up these relations, both of the relevant apps must've been loaded.

Django learned the hard way that allowing models to be imported at any time greatly complicated this process, and this introduced a range of hard-to-solve bugs. In 1.7 this process was greatly simplified, reducing the number of bugs, but in that simplification it was decided that all applications must've been loaded before any model can be imported.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced it by an __all__ statement which isn't working properly yet.